# Mysql wide search

Tags: php, html, mysql

Aloha, my aim is to be able to search info in my database in a "wide way"... 
I got a tag box, info is sent to mysql using this:

```
       $save= $_SESSION['cool'];
```

//lets say we taged and saved 50 words that have "red" and "white" in it  ////// and then sent it to database like so:

```
     $save= preg_replace('/([,])/', '$1 $2', $save); //this adds space. 
    $save= preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $save); // this deletes the comma.
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "0", "mydb"); 
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table (staff) VALUES ('$save') "));
```

Alright, so on my search page which is a tag box as well, I search info like this:

```
    $search= $_SESSION['search'];
```

// here we saved white, red and pink... //

```
$search= preg_replace('/([,])/', '$1 $2', $search); //this adds space. 
$search= preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $search); // this deletes the comma.
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "0", "mydb"); 
$fetch = ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE staff LIKE ('%$search%') "));
```

as you can see I have tried to use `% %`, but when I type words not in order the `echo` result is nothing...

My question ***is there a way of improving the search?*** So when I search "red" and "white" it will show all of the contents containing "red" or "white"...

Comment: Not clear from your question but you might want to look into FULLTEXT search

Comment: Have you found a satisfactory solution? How would you like to improve the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the search keys and look for them separately:

```
$search1= explode(',',$search); //splits search
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "0", "mydb"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE staff LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND staff LIKE '%", $search1) . "%'";
$fetch = ($mysqli->query($query));
```

Comment: Do you think this is an improvement? It is independent of the order of search words. What else would you like to support?